# How can I add a template page on A drupal basic page

Tags: drupal

Am using a bootstrap theme for a website am developing and i want to start adding content on Pages. Is there a way  I can add my own custom page without using Basic pages in drupal or Can I still work with Basic pages and come up with a custom page?

Answer (score 0):

Drupal provides a way to override themes. You can override bootstrap theme by using subtheme. Bootstrap theme provides a subtheme(starterkits) and follow below steps.
You can follow steps in below link to override the bootstrap theme using subtheme.
[How to Create a Drupal 8 Bootstrap Subtheme](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/create-a-drupal-8-bootstrap-subtheme-using-cdn/)

If is  it is drupal 6 or drupal 7 you can override page.tpl.php.

Answer (score 0):

copy file in bootstrap folder `theme/bootstrap/templates/node`   copy file--> `node.html.twig`

first create a content type  like ' `event`' then create  folder `templates/node`

pest file in bootstrap child folder `theme/bootstrap_child/templates/node`  pest file-->put file  `node--event.html.twig`

in file we write custom code :)